# No classDefFoundError for class in android library

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I have library A (stripe lib) . I have converted Example App of library A (stripe example app) to android library.
Now I am showing activity from Example App library. and it is showing proper activity from Example App lib
But problem is when that activity try to refer class from library A (stripe lib) it giving classDefFoundError .
Please help.

My android app have library references for both library A and Example App library.there is no build error for references.

Comment: is your app crashing or you are not able to extend some class ? What's the issue ?

Comment: @prateek app is crashing because giving following error 02:38:05.660: E/AndroidRuntime(2263): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.stripe.android.model.Card

Comment: Is Card an Activity ?

Comment: No its model class. it just data object.

Comment: One more thing when I run Example App of library A (as project) it runs successful it access com.stripe.android.model.Card with no errors.

Comment: Well you must check the `androidmanifest.xml` file in the example app and compare it to the one that you have for your project. You must be missing some activity declaration or something like that

Comment: I have checked that they are in proper way. And com.stripe.android.model.Card  not activity at all.